# Extract values before specific characters of one column in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, extract

How could I extract `area` values from `address` column in the follow dataframe?

```
                                                               address     quantity   price  
0                         711-2880 Nulla St. Mankato Mississippi 96.5㎡          2       20   
1                  P.O. Box 283 8562 Fusce Rd. Frederick Nebraska 206㎡          3       13   
2  606-3727 Ullamcorper. Street Roseville NH 115㎡ 11523 (786) 713-8616          5       23    
3                   Ap #867-859 Sit Rd. Azusa New York 39 square metre          3       32   
4             7292 Dictum Av. San Antonio MI 470㎡ 47096 (492) 709-6392          5       45
```

Please note it's the **values** before of either `㎡` or `square metre`.

The desired output will like this:

```
                                                               address   area    quantity  price  
0                         711-2880 Nulla St. Mankato Mississippi 96.5㎡   96.5          2     20  
1                  P.O. Box 283 8562 Fusce Rd. Frederick Nebraska 206㎡  206.0          3     13  
2  606-3727 Ullamcorper. Street Roseville NH 115㎡ 11523 (786) 713-8616  115.0          5     23  
3                   Ap #867-859 Sit Rd. Azusa New York 39 square metre   39.0          3     32  
4             7292 Dictum Av. San Antonio MI 470㎡ 47096 (492) 709-6392  470.0          5     45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.extract`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'address': ['711-2880 Nulla St. Mankato Mississippi 96.5㎡', 'P.O. Box 283 8562 Fusce Rd. Frederick Nebraska 206㎡', '606-3727 Ullamcorper. Street Roseville NH 115㎡ 11523 (786) 713-8616', 'Ap #867-859 Sit Rd. Azusa New York 39 square metre', '7292 Dictum Av. San Antonio MI 470㎡ 47096 (492) 709-6392']})
df['area'] = df['address'].str.extract(r"(\d+\.?\d*)\s*(?=㎡|\bsquare metre\b)")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                             address  area
0       711-2880 Nulla St. Mankato Mississippi 96.5㎡  96.5
1  P.O. Box 283 8562 Fusce Rd. Frederick Nebraska...   206
2  606-3727 Ullamcorper. Street Roseville NH 115㎡...   115
3  Ap #867-859 Sit Rd. Azusa New York 39 square m...    39
4  7292 Dictum Av. San Antonio MI 470㎡ 47096 (492...   470
```

Comment: Many thanks. Is it regex match method you're using?

Comment: @ahbon. Yes it is

Comment: I dont understand how could avoid to extract other `values` before `㎡` or `square metre`? Btw, is it possible use `rsplit` or `split`?

Comment: Sorry i do not understand

Comment: For example, in `711-2880 Nulla St. Mankato Mississippi 96.5㎡`, `711`, `2880` and `96.5` are all number values in left side of `㎡`, just wondering how could you method only takes `96.5` instead of all three.

Comment: Oh ok...i use regex Lookahead pattern --> `(?=)`